# When resizing the form, the image doesn't get centered nor zooming in or out works

Tags: vb.net, winforms, screenshot

I have this code which should resize correctly an image in VB2010 inside a form - it is like this, so it should theoretically work together with the zoom function, which has a similar syntax. What I want to achieve simply is that the imgZoom picture box stays centered the entire time.

Yesterday it worked just fine, today I didn't touch anything regarding this code, and it just randomly broke.

Here's the code of the form:
'''

````
Private Sub Form4_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            imgZoom = New PictureBox()
            ' Add the picture box to the form's controls collection
            Me.Controls.Add(imgZoom)
            imgZoom.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
            If imgZoom.Image.Width = 0 And imgZoom.Image.Width = 0 Then
                Return
            Else
                imgZoom.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
                Dim Ori_pos As New System.Drawing.Rectangle()
                Ori_pos.X = imgZoom.Left
                Ori_pos.Y = imgZoom.Top
                Ori_pos.Height = imgZoom.Height
                Ori_pos.Width = imgZoom.Width

                imgZoom.Location = New Point((Me.Width - imgZoom.Width) / 2, (Me.Height - imgZoom.Height) / 2)
            End If
        Catch ex As NullReferenceException
            Return
        End Try

        imgZoom.Width = Me.Width
        imgZoom.Height = Me.Height
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form4_Resize(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize

        Try
            imgZoom = New PictureBox()
            Me.Controls.Add(imgZoom)

            imgZoom = New PictureBox()
            ' Add the picture box to the form's controls collection
            Me.Controls.Add(imgZoom)
            imgZoom.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
            If imgZoom.Image.Width = 0 And imgZoom.Image.Width = 0 Then
                Return
            Else
                imgZoom.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
                Dim Ori_pos As New System.Drawing.Rectangle()
                Ori_pos.Height = imgZoom.Height
                Ori_pos.Width = imgZoom.Width
                Ori_pos.X = (Me.Width - imgZoom.Width) / 2
                Ori_pos.Y = (Me.Width - imgZoom.Width) / 2
            



                imgZoom.Location = New Point((Me.Width - imgZoom.Width) / 2, (Me.Height - imgZoom.Height) / 2)
            End If
        Catch ex As NullReferenceException
            Return
        End Try


    End Sub
```
````

'''

````
Private Sub HScroll1_Scroll(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.ScrollEventArgs) Handles HScroll1.Scroll
        Label1.Text = Trim(Str(HScroll1.Value)) & "%"

        Tmp_Pos.Top = Ori_pos.Top - (((Ori_pos.Height * HScroll1.Value / 100) - Ori_pos.Height) / 2)
        Tmp_Pos.Left = Ori_pos.Left - (((Ori_pos.Width * HScroll1.Value / 100) - Ori_pos.Width) / 2)
        Tmp_Pos.Height = (Ori_pos.Height * HScroll1.Value / 100)
        Tmp_Pos.Width = (Ori_pos.Width * HScroll1.Value / 100)

        imgZoom.Visible = False
        imgZoom.Top = Tmp_Pos.Top
        imgZoom.Left = Tmp_Pos.Left
        imgZoom.Height = Tmp_Pos.Height
        imgZoom.Width = Tmp_Pos.Width
        imgZoom.Visible = True
    End Sub
```
````

And for the zoom function, it's a scrollbar that should be zooming, but it just does nothing now. Yesterday, this same exact code was working.
Basically, now when it loads in, it rightfully puts it to the center,[image]

but when I try to resize it, it just - doesn't, even though there is the code to make it resize.The zoom also decided also that it wasn't a good day to be working.
[image]

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Doesn't look like your PictureBox has an image nor a size.  Why do you create it twice in a resize event?  You shouldn't be creating controls in a resize event.  Too many fireworks.

Comment: Easiest way (no code) to keep a control at the center of a container is using a [`TableLayoutPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/tablelayoutpanel-control-overview?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) with 1 column and 1 row as container. Put the child (here the PictureBox) in it, then it's enough to set `Anchor` of child to `None` to have in always in the center of container. Now you decide about the size and location of container. You can dock it to fill the parent.

Comment: Not sure I see the reasoning for anything more complicated than simply using the straight docking and/or anchoring properties.